# Division into pages with an EOP tag in a table tag

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file that contains several paragraph tags
Each paragraph has different types of tags that are under the content tag
The file contains an EOP tag in various places and I use a function to divide into a separate DIV for each problem page that EOP is sometimes found Inside an internal tag in the attached example, inside the table tag and when retrieving all the data in the table is received including after the EOP tag, how can the data in the table be retrieved only up to the EOP tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <statement>
    <mainBody>
       <paragraph>
        <heading> heading</heading>
        <content>
          <p>bla bla bla bla bla </p>
          <eop/>
        </content>
      </paragraph>
          <eop/>    <paragraph>
        <content>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <p>titile</p>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>data1</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <eop/>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>data2</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </content>
    </paragraph>
    </mainBody>
  </statement>
</root>

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="preprocessed">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="preprocess"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    body {
                        direction: rtl;
                    }

                    div.page {
                        margin: 1cm;
                        padding: 1cm;
                        border: 1px solid #000;
                        height: 27.7cm;
                        width: 19cm;
                        background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
                        page-break-after: always;
                    }

                    div.page:last-child {
                        page-break-after: avoid;
                    }

                    thead {
                        display: table-header-group;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$preprocessed/node()"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="preprocess">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="preprocess"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="paragraph" mode="preprocess">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::eop)">
            <paragraph>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::eop)]"/>
            </paragraph>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table" mode="preprocess">
        <xsl:variable name="thead" select="thead"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tbody/node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::eop)">
            <table>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::eop)]"/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mainBody">
        <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
            <div class="page">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="heading">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="table">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::node()" group-starting-with="eop">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="thead">
        <thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbody">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

 

  
    <xsl:template match="th">
        <th>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="td">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider to edit your question and to show us the desired XSLT transformation result. What is going to happen with tables or other elements that have an `eop` element somewhere inside? Do you want to omit some content from the table? Do you want to split the table for each eop? In what way exactly?

Comment: I think your EOP tag is an example of what is sometimes called a "milestone" element, and you'll probably find some good ideas if you search for "XSLT milestone". This kind of processing comes up a lot when dealing with TEI documents.

Answer (score 0):

With these kind of problems, you need to group all kind of nodes with e.g. `xsl:for-each-group select=".//node()" group-ending-with="eop"` and then you can recreate the subtree containing the `current-group()` using `intersect` in a separate mode; let's assume, to focus on the table problem, the input is e.g.

```
<content>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <p>titile</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>data1</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <eop/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>data2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</content>
```

then code like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="split">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="split"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <html>
            <head>
              <title>Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$split/node()"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="split" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="table" mode="split">
        <xsl:for-each-group select=".//node()" group-ending-with="eop">
          <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::table/node()" mode="build-tree"/>
          </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="build-tree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
       
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="build-tree">
      <xsl:if test=". intersect current-group()/ancestor-or-self::node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node() intersect current-group()/ancestor-or-self::node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="table/thead" mode="build-tree">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="eop" mode="build-tree"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for that sample input outputs two tables where the `tbody` of each contains the stuff before or after the `eop`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <content>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>
                     <p>titile</p>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p>data1</p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>
                     <p>titile</p>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p>data2</p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </content>
   </body>
</html>
```

The treatment of the `thead` is a special case as it is not part of the subtree of a current group but I assumed that you want the thead to appear in any of the splitted tables for semantic reason.